# javascript array behaving like pointers

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I am changing the value of a copy of the original variable the original variable is getting changed.

The code below

```
function test(){
  var original= ['','','','1',''];
  var copyy=original;
  copyy[3]="2"; 
  console.log(original);
}
```

The console output is

```
 ["", "", "", "2", ""]
```

Not able to wrap my head around this. 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfv4uwed/2/)

Comment: If you want an array in memory to be cloned, you have to do so explicitly, it'll never happen automatically

Comment: Chage this  var copyy = original; To  var copyy = [...original]; this may help